# Weblogic application switches back to http after secure login via https

Tags: ssl, weblogic

I have successfully configured SSL on Weblogic 9.2 MP3. I am able to login securely into the application using https and continue working on the application using https protocol. This is true in the case when user accesses the application giving following URL: https:/servername:7002/

If the user tries to access the above URL via HTTP i.e. http:/servername:7001/, application automatically redirects to https:/servername:7002/ page. However after user has been successfully authenticated by the server, the protocol switches to http.

Is there any configuration that i might have missed on weblogic server or application side?

Appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

You've most likely configured the web.xml to allow https only on the login URL

Something in the `<security-constraint>` section like this

`<url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>` with

```
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
```

Change the url-pattern above to suit the patterns you wish to keep as https