# https getting converted to http

Tags: http, https, weblogic, reverse-proxy

I am using Microsoft IIS to proxy requests for WebLogic server.

I've enabled https on IIS.

```
 [http://webserver gives error that 'page must be viewed on https' and https://webserver gives content of Default.htm file]
```

I've enabled https on WebLogic Server.

```
[http://weblogic:7001/myapp/test.jsp and https://weblogic:7002/myapp/test.jsp both works]
```

Communication b/w IIS and WebLogic Server is on https.

The issue is when I access application on https using webserver URL `(https://webserver/myapp/test.jsp)` I do get response (content of test.jsp) but when I print request.getRequestURL() in a filter, I get http URL `(http://webserver/myapp/test.jsp)`. This is causing a issue while doing sendRedirect()...

Why are my https URLs getting converted to http? Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986399/https-getting-converted-to-http

Comment: Hi, you mistakenly referenced my question only. Thanks.

Comment: Whoops - meant this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832785/weblogic-application-switches-back-to-http-after-secure-login-via-https

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp - this almost could have solved my issue but no. I have a web server (IIS) in front of app server. If I do configuration suggested in that post, it adds app server https port to web server url - which doesn't work. For example, 'http://webserver/myapp/test.jsp' or 'https://webserver/myapp/test.jsp' is changed to 'https://webserver:7002/myapp/test.jsp' and that doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you disable http entirely on the weblogic side? Uncheck listen port enabled for the server just to see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solved my issue:

If a plug-in is communicating to WebLogic application server then do following –
Environments > Servers > select your server > General > Advanced > check WebLogic Plug-In Enabled

Thanks again.